# What is the output format of the ssd_mobiledet_edgetpu_coco TFLite model from Tensorflow Detection model zoo?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I am attempting to run the ssd_mobiledet_edgetpu_coco model from the TF model zoo (available [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md#mobile-models)) on an NPU. The model itself runs perfectly fine, but the output format is unexpected and doesn't conform to any documentation (that I have been able to find).

Printing the model outputs, this is what I get (simplified)

```
BoxPredictor_0/BoxEncodingPredictor/BiasAdd shape: [1, 20, 20, 12]
BoxPredictor_0/ClassPredictor/BiasAdd shape: [1, 20, 20, 273]
BoxPredictor_1/BoxEncodingPredictor/BiasAdd shape: [1, 10, 10, 24]
BoxPredictor_1/ClassPredictor/BiasAdd shape: [1, 10, 10, 546]
BoxPredictor_2/BoxEncodingPredictor/BiasAdd shape: [1, 5, 5, 24]
BoxPredictor_2/ClassPredictor/BiasAdd shape: [1, 5, 5, 546]
BoxPredictor_3/BoxEncodingPredictor/BiasAdd shape: [1, 3, 3, 24]
BoxPredictor_3/ClassPredictor/BiasAdd shape: [1, 3, 3, 546]
BoxPredictor_4/BoxEncodingPredictor/BiasAdd shape: [1, 2, 2, 24]
BoxPredictor_4/ClassPredictor/BiasAdd shape: [1, 2, 2, 546]
BoxPredictor_5/BoxEncodingPredictor/BiasAdd shape: [1, 1, 1, 24]
BoxPredictor_5/ClassPredictor/BiasAdd shape: [1, 1, 1, 546]
```

The only documentation pertaining to these models that I could find is [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/object_detection/overview).
It implies that I should expect the output to be four arrays, which clearly isn't the case.

I suspect that the different outputs relate to different bounding box sizes, and that I am supposed to join them somehow, but the specifics elude me at the moment.

Is there any documentation available for these models anywhere?